# Android notification is not showing as a message

Tags: android, android-notifications

The notification it self is working good, but not as I want. It vibrates and shows the icon defined but not as a Watsapp Notification and in the `setCategory` I put `CATEGORY_MESSAGE` but still, nothing!

on my App class i put :

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,CHANNEL_NAME,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription(CHANNEL_DESC);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

Fragment :

```
private void T(String message){
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentTitle("Test")
            .setColor(0xff123456)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.com_facebook_button_icon)
            .setCategory(CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setPriority(PRIORITY_HIGH);
    NotificationManagerCompat compat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
    compat.notify(1,mBuilder.build());

}
```

This is How I want it to notify :

[image]

This is how is current notifying

[image]

I'm using the SDK 27

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "not as a Whatsapp notification". If it is showing the desired icon and title, are you perhaps referring to the actions like 'Reply' and 'Mark as Read'?

Comment: It's not popping out like any other notification on top of the screen. It just vibrates and show  the icon

Comment: You want it to pop up over other apps like shown here, in the Heads-up section?  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#Heads-up

Comment: Yeah, but it works only with api 21 >. I want something on `NotificationManagerCompat` level. I was watching a tutorial about this, on his phone pops out but mine doesn't.

Comment: In which API levels is your notification showing expected behaviour, and where is it not?

Comment: I updated my question!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190906/discussion-between-thegamer007-and-nathiel-paulino).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussing with OP in chat, here's my best explanation about what could have happened:

A notification channel can only be created once, after which it becomes immutable to the app. It can only be tweaked by the user through the Settings. If someone follows the examples in the official docs first, they might create the channel with `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT`. After this, even if they change the code later, the channel will remain at level 'High: Make Sound' and not be set to 'Urgent: Make Sound and pop on screen' as desired. [Docs on importance level](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#importance)

---

The code in the question is perfectly fine, and should create a channel with the 'Urgent' level when installed for the first time. In any case, uninstalling the app manually and then installing it again will recreate the channels, setting the level to whatever is mentioned in the latest code.